# Google App Engine: Python UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to set up a basic prototype with Google App Engine, and I'm getting the following error with the Google App Engine Launcher when trying to deploy:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)`

I found [this related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906948/google-app-engine-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe2-in-p), but I'm not quite sure how to correctly specify the decoding in my example. I'm using the following Python code:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get (self, q):
    if q is None:
      q = 'index.html'

    path = os.path.join (os.path.dirname (__file__), q)
    self.response.headers ['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write (template.render (path, {}))

def main ():
  application = webapp.WSGIApplication ([('/(.*html)?', MainHandler)], debug=True)
  util.run_wsgi_app (application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main ()
```

Thanks for any assistance here.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393758/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe5-in-position-0-ordinal

Comment: thanks dlebech; I hadn't found that thread earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure index.html is unicode ('utf-8' encoded) with your editor.

And I suggest you use webapp2, jinja and WSGI because webapp (django) template has been depricated.
Now you use old style Python 2.5 coding for app engine.

Docs:

- http://blog.notdot.net/tag/webapp2
- http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe
- http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python

Comment: Thanks for the info, voscausa-- I'll check out those resources you mentioned.